# Gson parser crashes due to blank character

Tags: java, gson

I have a file in JSON format. Gson parser crashes when it encounters a blank in it, as in State = "West Virginia", but it can parse "West-Virginia" where the blank character is replaced. I am using `BufferedReader` in Java.

But if I pass the same string hard-coded, the parser works.

```
import java.io.* ;

import com.google.gson.*;

public class gson_test {
    public static void main(String[] args)  throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader br2 = null ;
        String jsonStr =  "[{month = august, weather:clear}, [333] , {addr : {place = {city = city_name, county : its_name}, state = \"West Virginia\" } } ]" ;
        // System.out.printf("json-str : %s \n", jsonStr);
        GsonParseStr(jsonStr, (JsonElement) null );
        try  {
            String file2read_json = "c:\\enter\\filename\\here";  
            br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2read_json));
            // https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Array-Examples
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls().create();
            Object obj2 = gson.fromJson(br2, Object.class); // parses json-str into an object
            GsonParseStr(obj2.toString(), (JsonElement) null );
        }  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
            if (br2 != null)  {
                br2.close();
            }

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    static void GsonParseStr(String jsonStr, JsonElement elem)  {
        JsonParser parser2 = new JsonParser();
        elem = parser2.parse(jsonStr);   // this stmt crashes for the blank char 
        System.out.printf("parse str : %s \n", jsonStr);

    }
}
```

My file's content is:

```
[{month = august, weather:clear}, [333] , {addr : {place = {city = city_name, county : its_name}, state = "West.Virginia" } } ]
```

If I change "West.Virginia" to "West Virginia" the program crashes.

The file should get parsed the same way as 'file-contents in the form of raw string'.

PS : As suggested by JPinzon, I need quotes around (West Virginia) in the file, which I did have. But they have to be further escaped. Thus : (State: "West Virginia") won't do; it should be (State: "\"West Virginia\""). Optionally, the key 'State' can have double-quotes around it, but that is optional.

Comment: That's not valid json...

Comment: First of all, your file doesn't contain proper Json. Also, log `jsonStr` before the crashing statement see what you are getting from the file, you said that if you pass in the same string hardcoded it works, that probably means the string you're getting from the file is different. There's no way you are inputing the same string and getting different results.

Comment: I should add that the json.org home page specifies key:value as the syntax, but my file (admittedly not in that format) has some key=value constructs which Gson handles equally well. I observed that '=' sign is also handled correctly by Gson in some online discussions, tried using it myself, and Gson has no issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing your JSON to this:

```
[{"month":"august", "weather":"clear"}, [333], {"addr":{"place":{"city":"city_name", "county":"its_name"}, "state":"West Virginia"}}]
```

... or nicely formatted:

```
[
    {
        "month":"august",
        "weather":"clear"
    },
    [
        333
    ],
    {
        "addr":{
            "place":{
                "city":"city_name",
                "county":"its_name"
            },
            "state":"West Virginia"
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you debug, you will see that the string `obj2.toString()` doesn't contain quotes around "West Virginia" because the `gson.fromJson(br2, Object.class)` has removed them while parsing. That's why it crashes.

To avoid this error you can try adding escaped quotes in your file like this `state = "\"West Virginia\""`

Comment: I made the change suggested by you, and now the code does not crash. The code can parse that file even if there is no double-quote anywhere in it, except around "West Virginia". And in that case, the quote has to be escaped. Tricky. JSON specs mention quotes around key-names (example "key": "value"), but even if I remove the quotes (key: value), Gson is fine with it. And where quotes are needed, there is one more layer involved where the quote is escaped within the outer quote.

Comment: I just told you what the Gson method was doing (removing the quotes while parsing) and how to avoid the error, but if you want to do it the right way you should fix your JSON (as the other answer suggest) and use a `JsonReader` in the parse method instead of using `toString()` in the `BufferedReader` (`new JsonReader(new FileReader(file2read_json))`.